# Grant someone the right to show the indicative execution plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, acl

How can I grant someone the right to run the execution plan in Management Studio 2012.

My details for the MSSQL Server Management Studio are the following:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                                             2.6 3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 9.10.9200.17054
Microsoft .NET Framework                                    4.0.30319.34209
Operating System                                            6.1.7601
```

I hope that is sufficient information.

Edit:
I have the full rights as the system administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
USE db
Go
GRANT SHOWPLAN To User
```